# Unable to use $.getJSON in html page

Tags: html, getjson, mustache

this is going seem a very noob question, but is there any reason why this HTML page below wouldn't work?  It just loads a blank page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Test Page</title>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/2.3.0/mustache.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="mypanel"></div>

<script>
    $.getJSON(
        "Data.txt",
        function (data) {
            var template = "<h1>{{ name }}</h1>";
            var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
            $('#mypanel').html(html);
        }
    );
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Also, as I just trying to learn, the "Data.txt" file is located in the same directory as the HTML file and only contains the following text:

```
{ name: "John" }
```

Thanks so much for any help with this!

Comment: Try putting quotes around  'name': `{ "name": "John" }`

Comment: @sideroxylon Thanks for your input, I've just tried it, but no success.

Comment: Have you checked the console to confirm the data is being received?

Comment: Now I'm showing my ignorance:  How do you check the console?  Is it by using the developer tools on Chrome?

Comment: Yes - network tab.  It should show the response from your request.

Comment: Found it, and this is the message: Failed to load file:Data.txt: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
send @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4

Comment: There's your answer.  If you're testing on `file`, you'll need to set up a local server.

Answer (score 0):

I would rename the data file to Data.json

I have success with using fetch like this:

```
fetch('Data.json')
            .then(blob => blob.json())
            .then(data => {
            var template = "<h1>{{ name }}</h1>";
            var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
            $('#mypanel').html(html); 
            });
```